# Replace first character in string

Tags: powershell

I have a CSV file where I want to replace the first character that is 0 with +46 but I can't make this work as I want to.

I have the following code that works, but it works on all zeroes and not only the first one:

```
$csv = Import-Csv test.csv
$csv | ForEach-Object {
    $_.mobile = $_.mobile.Replace("0", "+46")
}
$csv | Export-Csv -Encoding "UTF8" new-test.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Any idea how to make this work only on the first character in the string?

Comment: "the first character that is 0" or "the first character, *if* it is 0"?

Comment: As `+46` is Sweden's country calling code, it looks like this is about converting phone numbers from domestic to international format.

Comment: @vonPryz That was my impression as well, thus the question :)

Comment: VonPryz is correct about the conversion to International numberformat

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This happens as `String.Replace()` will replace [all the occurrences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx).

In order to only replace the first one, use regular expressions. By using the beginning of line anchor, `^`, the replacement is limited to start of string. Like so,

```
$_.mobile = $_.mobile -replace "^0", "+46"
```

Comment: This works great so thank you. As you can see this isnt what i usually do but i guess you have to start somewhere